# Did Satoshi transfer several bitcoin domains before disappearing?

Tags: privacy, satoshi-nakamoto, satoshi

Wikipedia Satoshi's page says that:

> Nakamoto continued to collaborate with other developers on the bitcoin software until mid-2010. Around this time, he handed over control of the source code repository and network alert key to Gavin Andresen, transferred several related domains to various prominent members of the bitcoin community, and stopped his involvement in the project.

Is the domain transfer information correct? Does anyone know which ones?

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satoshi_Nakamoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was just bitcoin.org and bitcointalk.org.

He's the [3rd user](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=3) on bitcointalk.org. It was transfer to theymos.

Edit: Correction, bitcointalk.org was not a domain transfer according to Pieter Wuille.

Comment: bitcointalk.org was bitcoin.org/forum at the time.

Comment: Wonder how anonymous those domain names registrations can remain, to the powers in charge...